# Error No default container found with grails-2.2.1

Tags: tomcat, grails

I try to start a web app thanks to grails run-app command but I've got the following error :

```
| Compiling 1 source files.....

| Compiling 1 source files.....

| Error No default container found. Please install a container plugin such as 'tomcat' first.
```

BuildConfig.groovy contains build `:tomcat:$grailsVersion`

I have no idea about resolving this problem.

Thanks for your help!

BuildConfig.groovy file:-

```
grails.servlet.version = "2.5" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

// uncomment (and adjust settings) to fork the JVM to isolate classpaths
//grails.project.fork = [
  // run: [maxMemory:1024, minMemory:64, debug:false, maxPerm:256]
//]

// Plugin Directory Location
grails.project.plugins.dir="./plugins"


grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()

        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()

        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
       mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
       mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
       mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
       mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
       mavenRepo "http://dev.plutext.org/svn/docx4j/trunk/docx4j/m2"
       mavenRepo "https://webdavclient4j.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/webdavclient4j/trunk/m2"
    mavenRepo "https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/"
        grailsRepo "https://grails.org/plugins"

    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.

        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.22'
        compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5'
        compile 'org.docx4j:docx4j:3.2.2'
                compile 'com.github.groovy-wslite:groovy-wslite:1.1.0'
        runtime ":docx4jImportXHTML:3.2.2"
        runtime ":xhtmlrenderer:3.0.0"
        runtime ":itext:2.1.7"
        runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.18'
    }

    plugins {
        runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
        runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
       //  runtime ":resources:1.1.6"
        compile ":jquery-ui:1.8.24"
    compile ":jasper:1.10.0"
    compile ":ckeditor:4.4.1.0" 
        // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
        //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"
       //compile ":twitter-bootstrap:3.3.1"
        compile ':spring-security-core:1.2.7.3'
        compile ":spring-security-ldap:1.0.6"
        compile ":ldap:0.8.2"        
        compile ":audit-logging:0.5.4"
        compile ":export:1.5"
        build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.3.2"
        compile ':cache:1.0.1'
        compile ":mail:1.0.7"
        compile ":asset-pipeline:2.4.3"
        runtime ":webxml:1.4.1"
        compile ":wslite:0.7.2.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried "grails clean" and "grails refresh-dependencies" but I've got the error "| Error No default container found. Please install a container plugin such as 'tomcat' first." with grails run-app.

Comment: Can you show the entire `BuildConfig.grovy` file?

Comment: @ Jeff Scott Brown : flow above BuildConfig.grovy file